# z/OSMF REST API Error: Rest API failure with HTTP(S) status 500 category: 6 rc: 8 reason:513 message:fopen()failed

Tags: visual-studio-code, ibm-cloud, mainframe

I'm using the Zowe CLI to access an IBM z/OS instance. I keep getting this error.

```
Error: Rest API failure with HTTP(S) status 500 
       category: 6 rc: 8 reason:513 message:fopen()failed
```

I've restarted VScode and retraced the steps to make I was making the right request for jobs and files. Im stumped.

Comment: What is the service you are trying to access?  Do you have an example of code ?  Your question is missing enough context to help you.

Comment: Learn how to ask a good question, that means __show your command__  that is failing.  Learn how to lookup error codes for Z/OS.  In this case it is possible that you (or something else, or someone else) has the same target dataset or member file opened in another tool at the same time you are trying to access it, and sharing is not possible with the requested modes.

Comment: I believe we had a simular issue (not sure about reason 513) in the past. This was due to an incorrect conversion for line endings by zowe. This has been addressed late last year. Perhaps updating you CLI version resolves this. If there’s a chance that you use TSO segments, looking at the TSU job output could also show helpfull info

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I have solved it in this way:

Click this link https://slack.openmainframeproject.org/ and register in the community.

From within the #cobol-programming-course Slack channel , send a Direct Message (DM) to the Zih_COBOL bot by typing: /dm @Zih_COBOL

1. Enter your Mainframe ID,  followed by the email you used to register for the COBOL course --> **/dm @Zih_COBOL /Zxxxxxx registrationEmail@Email.com**
2. If the email matches a valid ID in the registration DB, then password is reset
3. Use the password provided by Zih_COBOL to login

Then follow the steps in vscode and you will get your connection. I hope you can connect.